# Heroku App Has 0 Dynos

Tags: python, heroku, flask

My Heroku app has 0 dynos.

I tried adding one but it did not work.

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

How do you add a dyno?

Comment: What does `heroku logs` say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go to the web interface if you login to heroku.com and use the slider like the one shown below.

[image]

You will also need a valid `Procfile` for the scaling up to work.

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten to add the Procfile